# Add data to gridview template field using jquery?

Tags: jquery, templates, gridview, asp-classic, using

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
           <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="isbn">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="bookname">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
```

How to add data to gridview template using jquery ?
I know how to bind server side; I need to know that how to bind data using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on class or Id and how it's rendering in browser, you can append data.